# symfony validates if another field is specific value

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I'm trying to write a validation for a field(1) to be required if another field(3) is option 'a', and a different field(2) if 3 is 'b'.  How would I go about doing that?

EDIT:
It is for an Entity.  I'll post a sample of what I'm trying.

```
/**
*@Assert\Collection(
*fields = { aName = @Assert\NotBlank(),
*           aAmount = @Assert\NotBlank() }
*/
protected $1;

/**
*@Assert\Collection(
*fields = { bName = @Assert\NotBlank(),
*           bAmount = @Assert\NotBlank() }
*/
protected $2;

/**
*@Assert\NotBlank()
*/
protected $3;
```

I need $1 to be required if $3 == 'a', and $2 if $3 =='b'.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use validation constraint: [Expression](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Expression.html)

Example:

```
/**
* @Assert\Expression(
 *     "not (this.getThird() == 'a' and this.getFirst() == null)",
 *     message="If third = 'a', first should be not null"
 * )
 */
protected $first;

/**
 * @Assert\Expression(
 *     "not (this.getThird() == 'b' and this.getSecond() == null)",
 *     message="If third = 'b', second should be not null"
 * )
 */
protected $second;

protected $third;

public function getFirst()
{
     return $this->first;   
}

public function getSecond()
{
     return $this->second;   
}

public function getThird()
{
     return $this->third;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try with a Callback constraint : http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html